# Loading and parsing a local JSON-file

Tags: python, django

I have a fully working function for displaying external JSON data from an URL

```
def object_api(request):
    
    url = 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/vehicles'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    
    arr = [dic for dic in data ]
    
    context = {
        'data': arr,
    } 

    return render(request, 'output.html', context)
```

Now I need to load a local file, e.g. example.txt filled with JSON-data.

How do I load such a file? My current problem is the transformation of data to a proper **"context"-variable**.

Comment: Instead of `data = response.json()`, use `data = json.load(open('/path/to/example.txt'))`

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for `json`? If not, it’s here https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with json lib

```
import json 

with open ("example.txt", "r") as file: 
    data = json.load(file)
```